# python folium map setting (prevent zooming and panning)

Tags: python, folium

I'm having some issues figuring out if folium can be restricted to a single instance of the world rather than allowing for panning and zooming into other instances?

What I mean is when I try some basic examples online, I get maps that looks like this when zoomed out:

[image]

While the output I want would only have one instance of each continent in the map rather than repeating them when panning / zooming out.

I used the following code to generate the linked image:

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import folium

#df_traffic = pd.read_csv('../input/ukTrafficAADF.csv')
df_acc = pd.read_csv('../input/accidents_2005_to_2007.csv', dtype=object)
map_hooray = folium.Map(location=[51.5074, 0.1278],
                    zoom_start = 11) # Uses lat then lon. The bigger the zoom number, the closer in you get
map_hooray # Calls the map to display
```

What modifications do I need to make the map only display one instance of the continents even when zoomed out?

Thanks!

Comment: i think you want either the `no_wrap` or `max_bounds` arguments for folium.Map, but i'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks so much! no_wrap = True restricts panning while max_bounds  = True restricts the map to one view of the continents. It does seem like max_bounds restricts the screen size to a smaller area (can't full screen view unless zoomed in).

Answer (score 5):

you should try in your notebook:

```py
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[-23, -46],
               zoom_start=5,
               zoom_control=False,
               scrollWheelZoom=False,
               dragging=False)

m
```

More info could be found here: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map

(if the url is breaking, change the reference number to the newest version =))

Comment: thank you, that is great. Now, I also notice that you can not scroll down the page. Is it possible to still scroll down the page, when the scrollWheelZoom is False. Would there be a solution for that?